# Probem of Classify's Tree Method in Batch Predict

Tags: bugs, machine-learning

```
$Version
```

> 12.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)

```
trainingset = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "Mushroom"}, "TrainingData"];
testset = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "Mushroom"}, "TestData"];
samples = testset[[All, 1]];

trainingData = RandomSample[trainingset, 1000];
```

```
c = Classify[trainingData, Method -> "DecisionTree", FeatureExtractor -> "DimensionReducedVector"]
```

[image]

```
c[samples[[79]], "Probabilities"]
```

> <|"edible" -> 0.975, "poisonous" -> 0.025|>

```
c[samples[[{1, 2, 79}]], "Probabilities"][[-1]]
```

> <|"edible" -> 0.975, "poisonous" -> 0.025|>

No difference.

```
c = Classify[trainingData, Method -> "GradientBoostedTrees", FeatureExtractor -> "DimensionReducedVector"]
```

[image]

```
c[samples[[79]], "Probabilities"]
```

> <|"edible" -> 0.998383, "poisonous" -> 0.00161739|>

```
c[samples[[{1, 2, 79}]], "Probabilities"][[-1]]
```

> <|"edible" -> 0.99807, "poisonous" -> 0.00193042|>

**0.998383 vs 0.99807**

```
c = Classify[trainingData, Method -> "RandomForest", FeatureExtractor -> "DimensionReducedVector"]
```

[image]

```
c[samples[[79]], "Probabilities"]
```

> <|"edible" -> 0.855689, "poisonous" -> 0.144311|>

```
c[samples[[{1, 2, 79}]], "Probabilities"][[-1]]
```

> <|"edible" -> 0.875449, "poisonous" -> 0.124551|>

**0.855689 vs 0.875449 - significant difference**

**The original version of the question**

Tested at 12.1, the problem seems to be existed a long time...

```
trainingset = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "Mushroom"}, "TrainingData"];
testset = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "Mushroom"}, "TestData"];
samples = testset[[All, 1]];

trainingData = RandomSample[trainingset, 1000];

c = Classify[trainingData, Method -> "DecisionTree"]
```

also happen in `GradientBoostedTrees` method, you can try several times to re-train the model to make this happen.

Since the batch predict is extremely important in speed aspect, I think this problem is very serious...

Batch Predict means use a trained model to predict several examples like this way: model[{example1,example2,}], something like listable attributes in some function, which is much faster

[image]

Comment: This really should state explicitly what the problem is. The term "batch predict" is nebulous.

Comment: I was able to reproduce. Upvoted and edited your question.

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev  OK, thanks for confirming that. This problem destroy my enthusiasm of playing Classify, since tree method is extremely important.

Comment: To restate the original question:  If you use the trained classifier, `c`,  to evaluate a single example , e.g., `c[ samples[[79]],  "Probabilities" ]`, you get a different answer than if you use the trained classifier to evaluate a list of examples, e.g., `c[samples[[{1, 2, 79}]],  "Probabilities"]`.

In fact, the problem is even worse than this:  If you evaluate a list of examples of the same point one gets different answers, e.g., `c[ {samples[[79]], samples[[79]] },  "Probabilities"]` returns the two different probability values, even though it is a list of the same examples.

Comment: Random speculation:  A similar non-deterministic prediction occurred in the older versions of SciKit-Learn (see:[ https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10065]. It appears to be fixed by a change to make the accumulation of the results of each tree thread safe (see:  [https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/9830 ])

Comment: @HyperGroups Did you report this to Wolfram Support?

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev yes, i reported, maybe more reporters will accelerate the fix time.

Comment: Fixed in 12.3.0.